# rails Calculation (price * quantity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi Im creating an ec site in my rails.

My migration:
(Item) has :name and :price.
(Basket_Item) has :item_id(fk), :basket_id(fk) and :quantity.

The system User will add some items to their basket.
So Basket_items is JOIN Table between (Item) and (Basket)
see like below.

What I want to do:

**Get a price of Item and get a quantity from Basket_Items which is selected by user. Then I want to create @total_price = item_price * item_quantity.**

Can anyone help me to create the @total_price please.

This is my a try code but it doesn't work on rails console.

```
Basket_items

class CreateBasketItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :basket_items do |t|
      t.references :basket, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :item, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.integer    :quantity, null: false, default: 1
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

///

```
Items

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.references :admin, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string  :name,  null: false, index: true
      t.integer :price, null: false
      t.text    :message

      t.string  :category, index: true
      t.string  :img 
      t.string  :Video_url
      t.text    :discription
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

///

This is my try a code but it doesn't work on rails console.

```
basket = current_user.prepare_basket
item_ids = basket.basket_items.select(:item_id)
items = basket.items.where(id: item_ids)
items_price = items.select(:price)
items_quantity = basket.basket_items.where(item_id: item_ids).pluck(:quantity)

def self.total(items_price, items_quantity)
  sum(items_price * items_quantity)
end

@total_price = basket.total(items_price, item_quantity)
```

Comment: You’re creating the `total` method as a class method, but you’re calling it on an instance of the `Basket` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:
You are trying to call a `class method` on an `instance` of the class. That's not gonna work, second you are passing in arrays into the calculation.

```rb
basket = current_user.prepare_basket
item_ids = basket.basket_items.select(:item_id)
items = basket.items.where(id: item_ids)
items_price = items.select(:price) # => Array of prices from the items in the basket
items_quantity = basket.basket_items.where(item_id: item_ids).pluck(:quantity) # => Array of quantities from the items in the basket

def self.total(items_price, items_quantity)
  sum(items_price * items_quantity) # => So this line will do: sum(['12,95', '9.99'] * [1, 3])
end

@total_price = basket.total(items_price, item_quantity)
```

As you can see, that ain't gonna work. First you need to change the method and remove the `self`.

```rb
def total(items_price, items_quantity)
  # ...
end
```

Now you can call the total method on a `basket` object: `basket.total(items_price, items_quantity)`

And inside the `total` method you need to loop through each items to do the calculation and add all the results.

```rb
def total(items_price, items_quantity)
  total_price = 0
  items_price.each_with_index do |price, index|
    total_price += price * items_quantity[index]
  end
  total_price
end
```

But this solution could also fail, because you don't know sure that the order in the `items_price` is matching with the order of `items_quantity`. So a better approach would be to do the calculation for each `basket_item` seperate.

```rb
# Basket model
def total
  total_price = 0
  basket_items.each do |basket_item|
    total_price += basket_item.total_price
  end
  total_price
end

# BasketItem model
def total_price
  quantity * item.price
end
```

Now you can call it like this: `basket.total`